# How does this site make their site on Google search interactive?

Tags: google-search

If you type in "[Boyce Avenue](http://google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=boyce%20avenue)" on Google, you'll see that there is a drop down where you can see more events. How can I achieve the same sort of thing with my own site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Event Information rich snippet available with Google Webmaster Tools.

[Webmaster Tools - Events](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506)

Answer (score 0):

If you search for [smleimberg](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=smleimberg) in google, since my Content Management System(CMLS) is [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/), it makes this data available for google automatically.

Comment: I'm talking about the tour date events.

Comment: Oh, ok, then you might want to change your Boyce Avenue link to [this](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=boyce%20avenue#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=boyce+avenue+tickets+tour+dates&pbx=1&oq=boyce+avenue+tickets+tour+dates&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11942l13173l3l13475l8l8l0l0l0l0l73l470l8l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=862141011cc102a&biw=1245&bih=683)